# How to import/veiw STL files in a wordpress website?

Tags: html, wordpress, import, stl

I'm starting a new WordPress website with the Divi plugin and I am needing to import and view an STL file and the volume of the object in the file. I'm pretty new to WordPress and any help is wonderful!

Thanks, Cameron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display a STL file on your site, which I assume is what you want to do, you need a plugin. You can find a few different ones [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/stl/).